# How to print out ASCII to a separate file.

Tags: abaqus

I am trying to print data using

```
*EL PRINT
```

to a separate file other that jobname.dat file.
Is there any way to do this?

PS: I know how to export the data from the odb file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can't reroute that kind of input-file keyword output request to a different file. I've listed some alternatives below:

- As you mention, you can script it using the Abaqus/Python API.
- You can manually print results to a file of your choosing from the Viewer.
- You can access the results file for postprocessing using a Fortran or C++ program (search for ABQMAIN).
- You can access results and write them to a file of your choosing during the analysis using the Fortran subroutine `URDFIL`.